# ColdFusion cfhttp looses metadata in uploading docx file

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am having a problem uploading a docx file. It looses 2 bytes after I upload and save it to the server. Here is my code.

```
<cffunction name="akamaiUpload" access="private" output="false">
    <cfargument name="filename" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="localpath" type="string" required="true">

    <cftry>

        <cfhttp url="http://sample.com/#arguments.filename#" method="post">
            <cfhttpparam type="file" name="user_file" file="#arguments.localpath#" />
        </cfhttp>

    <!--- catch any error, return the error message --->
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfreturn #cfcatch.message#>
    </cfcatch>

    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

I've found some code with the same issue and tried to apply their solution but still it didn't work. Here is the code.

```
<cffunction name="akamaiUpload" access="private" output="false">
    <cfargument name="filename" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="localpath" type="string" required="true">

    <cffile action="readbinary" file="#arguments.localpath#" variable="myfile">
        <cfset by=CreateObject("java","java.lang.String")>
        <cfset by.init(myfile, "iso-8859-1")>
        <cfset contentdivider=Hash("this is my divider for this")>

        <cfhttp method="POST" url="http://sample.com/#arguments.filename#" charset="iso-8859-1">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data; boundary=#contentDivider#">
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
        </cfhttp>       

    <!--- returning true for successful upload --->
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

Has anyone here experienced the same issue? Please share some suggestions.

Comment: How are you determining it is losing two (2) bytes?  If you use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), what does the actual cfhttp post look like?

Comment: I just check the size of the file before and after it was uploaded to the server using charles. On the other hand, i tried zipping the file before uploading to the server then i downloaded and unzipped it and when i check the file size there's no difference between the original and downloaded one.

Comment: (Edit) What does the raw POST look like in Charles (excluding the binary content)?. I remember a similar issue relating cfhttp and files, but ... it was *adding* a few bytes. For grins, any difference if you add a dummy field after the file field?

Comment: *I've found some code with the same issue* Can you post a link?